# Change value of one sibling with the value of another Java & XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have an XML file with the following structure:

```
<thing1>
    <thing2...>
        <member>
            <name>thename</name>
            <value>thevalue</value>
        </member>
        <member>
            <name>thename2</name>
            <value>thevalue2</value>
        </member>
        ...
    <thing2...>
<thing1>
```

I want to set the xml value of the <value> to the value of the <name> using something like:

```
myNodeList.item(1).setNodeValue(thename);
```

Actually I am able (I think) to get all the <member> of my file using xpath and java with:

```
NodeList nl = root.getElementsByTagName("member");
```

But I am strugling to get the value of the tags inside  in order to do my change. What's the proper way to do that please?

I tried to work on the 'show' but it does not seems to be the way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    Element show = (Element) nl.item(i);
    ... //trying things here but never return what I want
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so more or less, this is how I achieved this, in case anybody need it one day, this is for you!

```
   String exprName = "//member/name[1]";
            NodeList nodeNameList = (NodeList) path.evaluate(exprName, root, XPathConstants.NODESET);

            ArrayList<String> nameTags = new ArrayList<>();

 for (int j = 0; j < nodeNameList.getLength(); j++) {
                Node n2 = nodeNameList.item(j);
                nameTags.add(n2.getTextContent());
            }

            String exprValue = "//member/value[1]";
            NodeList nodeValueList = (NodeList) path.evaluate(exprValue, root, XPathConstants.NODESET);

            for (int j = 0; j < nodeValueList.getLength(); j++) {
                Node n2 = nodeValueList.item(j);

                String exprI4 = "i4";
                Node nodeI4 = (Node) path.evaluate(exprI4, n2, XPathConstants.NODE);

                if (nodeI4 != null) {
                    nodeI4.setTextContent("${" + nameTags.get(j) + "}");
                } else {
                    n2.setTextContent("${" + nameTags.get(j) + "}");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive function like this:

```java
public static void nodeChange(Node node){
    if("value".equals(node.getNodeName())){
        NodeList nodeList = node.getParentNode().getChildNodes();
        for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++){
            if("name".equals(nodeList.item(i).getNodeName())){
                node.setTextContent(nodeList.item(i).getTextContent());
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < node.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++){
        nodeChange(node.getChildNodes().item(i));
    }
}
```

So that you first call it for your `Document` object which makes it recursively bypass the document tree and change the `value` content to the `name` content on the same tree level.